# Finding a nested document and pushing a document into a nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So i started learning mongoDB and moongoose today. I have the following Schema:

```
{
    username: {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique: true,
        trim : true
    },
    routines : {
        type: [
            {   
                _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                name : String, 
                todos : [
                    {
                        _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                        todo : String, 
                        isCompleted : Boolean
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

for example:

```
{
   "username": "John",
   "routines": [
       {
          "_id" : 1234, //just for an example assume it to be as 1234
          "name" : "Trip plan",
          "todos" : [
             {
                "_id": 1213123,
                "todo": "book flight",
                "isCompleted" : "false"
             }....
          ]
       }......
    ]
}
```

what i want to do is, first i would select a document from collection, by using username, then in routines(Array of objects), i want to select a particular routine by id, which would be given by user in request body, now in the selected routine, i want to push into todos array.

For above example, suppose, selecting document with username john, then selecting an object from routines array with _id as 1234, then to its todos i will add a todo.

I have spent almost a day searching about how to do this, while doing this i learnt concepts like arrayFilters, projections. But still couldn't get how to do. Also i read many answers in Stack Overflow, i couldn't grasp much out of them.

PS:I am very new to MongoDB and mongoose, Chances that my question is very silly, and might not be good as per stack overflow standards, I apologize for the same.

Comment: @Gibbs i can't structure the query, i mean i should use findoneandupdate, then i gave the first filter so that i can select the correct document, but the issue that, i then also should find the routine with routine id, where to write that in findoneandupdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, you indeed want to use [arrayFilter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) to achieve this.

Here is a quick example:

```
// the user you want.
let user = user;

await db.routines.updateOne(
    {
        username: user.username
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "routines.$[elem].todos": newTodo
        }
    },
    {arrayFilters: [{'elem._id': "1234"}]}
);
```

Comment: I can understand your answer clearly, but for some reason its not working.

Comment: Could you elaborate? does the update just fail? are you sure a matching document exists?

Comment: Yes, i am sure a matching document exist, it didnt gave me any error, but its returning {
    "ok": 0,
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0
}

Comment: It is my fault as I wrote it with a syntax error. it's suppose to be `$[elem]` and not `[$elem]`. I just ran it on my local to confirm.